# How do I pass vm arguments using the java plugin in gradle?

Tags: java, gradle

I am using the Java plugin for gradle.
How do I pass in some vm arguments to the `>gradle test` command?

The arguments can be in the build.gradle as I always want them passed in.

Thanks

Comment: See https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:allJvmArgs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html):

**jvmArgs** 
The extra arguments to use to launch the JVM for the process. Does not include system properties and the minimum/maximum heap size.

```
apply plugin: 'java' // adds 'test' task

test {

  // set JVM arguments for the test JVM(s)
  jvmArgs '-XX:MaxPermSize=256m'

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify the `jvmArgs` argument for the `test` task.

```
test {
    jvmArgs '-XX:MaxPermSize=256m'
}
```

[Official documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html)